# Powering audio codec below recommended spec

Tags: power, audio-codec

I'm working on an audio project where I intend to use the PCM3060 audio codec ([datasheet here](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/slas533b/slas533b.pdf)). The datasheet says that the chip takes two power inputs :

- Vcc (Analog supply voltage) @ nominal 5V (recommended operating conditions  4.5V to 5.5V)
- Vdd (Digital supply voltage) @ nominal 3.3V

Providing the 5V will be a pain for me so my question is : **Being ok with a reduced analog output voltage range, can I get away with providing only 3.3V to Vcc ?**

My naive expectation is that, being for the analog side of the chip Vcc will mostly define the max range of the op-amps that would be involved in the process of generating the signal, and thus reducing Vcc would mostly only reduce the effective ouptut voltage range (and maybe to a lesser extent the dynamics of the output) but nothing would stop working and as I expect to not use the whole rated output range that would be perfectly ok for me.

That assumption is partly based on the observation that  most of the output caracteristics in the datasheet are specified as proportions of Vcc but as I have very little experience in electronics, let alone audio cicuitry, I don't know if typically DACs and ADCs would be that tolerant in regard to power supplies.

Note : 3.3V is outside the recommended operating conditions which is why I'm asking this question. 3.3V is well within the absolute max rating for Vcc so I'm at least sure it  won't damage the chip.

Comment: That's probably not a good idea.  But there are likely plenty of modern parts intended for 3.3v-only operation.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I actually  bought the chips before realizing that issue ...

Comment: 3.3V is well within the abs max ratings but not in the recommended operating conditions. Anyway, the chip accepts 3Vpp audio input so it wont be possible with 3.3V analog supply. Also if the internal operating points/conditions of the analog blocks are designed for 5V supply then audible distortion may show up while using 3.3V.

Comment: The datasheet specifically points out the allowable analog voltage range. The analog voltage supply you want to use is well outside that range. So the answer is "no." That said, you can always operate it outside its specs and see what happens. (Probably, given how far outside, not much good in the end.)

Comment: DC/DC step up is pretty easy thanks to fully integrated modules, e.g. "simpleswitcher" from TI. Anyway, that might be more expensive than just buying new codecs.